# Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'IData'. What is missing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, typescript, replace

I am tryign to create a cast function where a string with numbers is received as input, but when using the regex function "replace()" it doesn't recognize it.

Anyone know how can I declare "replace()" inside type IData?

```
interface IData{
    data:string | {
        replace: (()=>number),
    };
}

class Cast{

    castString(data:IData){
        return data.toString();
    }

    castNumber(data:IData){
        return data.replace(/\D+/g, '');
    }

}

export default new Cast;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? What are your inputs and what is your expected output?

Comment: if you are using the string type in input then there is already a built-in replace function for string type. Why do you need to create a custom one?

Comment: the input on castNumber would be "34bbb5", and the result should be 345. "data" is a string type, but when using the regex "replace" it throws Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'IData'.ts(2339)

Comment: Solved by declaring string without creating an interface, but im still curious how to declare properties inside properties in a interface

Comment: In `castNumber()`, the `data` parameter is of type `IData`.  That type does not have a `replace` member; it is only known to have a `data` member.  So you'd need `data.data.replace()` to even approach a solution here.  But since `data.data` is either a `string` or some other type with a `replace` method which needs no arguments and returns a `number`, you'd want to do further testing before calling it. I'm very confused. Please consider modifying the code so as to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link)](https://tsplay.dev/mZ8Aow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments so far, I think that there is a need to shortly explain types in JS (which translates to TS as well).

Primitive types in JavaScript (e.g. `string`, `number` and `boolean`) are no objects with functions, but rather only values. The functions you can call on them (like `replace` for a `string`) are actually from the so called `Boxed types`. They are the Object counterpart to the primitives. They can be used to either explicitly cast (`Number("123")`) or to wrap the primitive in an object (`new` `Number(123)`).

> Latter should be avoided, because this id done automatically by JS whenever needed. Like in your case: `"34bbb5".replace(...)` is changed to `new String("34bbb5").replace(...)` behind the scenes

**How does this information help?**

With that in mind, your goal seems to be to define a string type that has a different replace function definition. The new definition was meant to change the behavior of the `Sting.replace` function. Problem being, that it is only a definition. So, it does not affect the actual `String.replace` function.

**What are your options**

A TypeScript interface is only a definition present at compile time. So, by overloading the `replace` function definition you do not gain any code change. Consequentially, the following interface definition should suite your case just fine.

```
interface IData {
  data:string
}
```

Your `Cast` class seems to have the task to cast the `IData` either to a string or to a number. The first one is rather simple, as it means to simply return the value of the `data` attribute.

> You used the `toString()` method of the object that fullfills the `IData` interface. This actually calls the `Object.toString()` function which results in `"[object Object]"`.

The second cast method should return a number. Here you already provided most of the code, but you missed to call it on the `data` attribute (as pointed out by @jcalz).
So, you should call it on the `data` attribute and actually cast it to a number. You can use `+` or `Number()` or `parseInt()` for this. As you only have numbers in the string left, there is no difference in behavior.

The result would look like:

```
interface IData{
    data:string;
}

class Cast{
    castString(data:IData){
        return data.data.toString();
    }
    castNumber(data:IData){
        return Number(data.data.replace(/\D+/g, ''));
    }
}

export default new Cast;
```

**Tip**

You could also use `object destructuring` if you want

```
castString({data}: IData){
  return data.toString();
}
```