# Remove CNPJ/CPF/CEP punctuation with Google Apps Script (GAS)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

it gives an error saying that the function "replace does not exist"

```
function removerPontuacao(){
  let lastrow2 = sheet.getRange('AA1').getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow(); // código para ir para última linha 

  var cep = sheet.getRange("R" + lastrow2).getValue();
  cep = cep.replace(/\.|\-/g, '');
  sheet.getRange("R" + lastrow2).setValue(cep);

  var cnpj = sheet.getRange("D" + lastrow2).getValue();
  cnpj = cnpj.replace(/\/|\.|\-/g, '');
  sheet.getRange("D" + lastrow2).setValue(cnpj);
}
```

Comment: You can replace from `\.|\-` to `\W`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537146/property-replace-does-not-exist-on-type-idata-what-is-missing

Comment: You can replace from \.|\- to \W. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537146/property-replace-does-not-exist-on-type-idata-what-is-missing

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75032387/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0):

The error you quote indicated that the value in a cell is not a text string but a number, date or Boolean that lacks the `.replace()` method.

To make it work, get text strings in the format displayed in the spreadsheet with `.getDisplayValue()`, like this:

```js
  let cep = sheet.getRange('R' + lastrow2).getDisplayValue();
  // ...
  let cnpj = sheet.getRange('D' + lastrow2).getDisplayValue();
```